# AngularJS: How to update $scope after a promise response?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise

Disclaimer: I'm a beginner with AngularJS.

I'm trying to update $scope after a promise has returned, but it does not work. Here's the simplified code:

```
.controller('ChooseRewardCtrl', ['$scope', ...,
                                  function($scope, ...) {

    // scope data
    $scope.points = CardModel.points;

    // function called to refresh points
    $scope.refresh_points = function() {
      return CardModel.refresh_points() // This is a promise that changes CardModel.points value
      .then(function(data){
        $scope.$apply() // Throw error (cf. above)
      })
    }
}
```

I get a `Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $digest already in progress`
I saw lots of post about this error, but nothing that I can directly link to my problem.

Thanks!

Comment: Is CarModel.refresh_points() returning an ng.$q or a normal promise? If so, you shouldn't need $scope.$apply()

Comment: It's a Normal promise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
.then(function(data){
        $scope.points = CardModel.points;
      })
```

Answer (score 0):

you need not use $apply().

log your function parameter ('data') and see what does it contain.

It should contain value returned by promise.

assign the appropriate value to your scope variable.